# Angular Materials Installation Error

Tags: angular

I am getting the following warning when installing Angular Materials

```
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@5.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Now when I check my Angular version (ng --version) I see:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0-rc.3
Node: 9.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0-rc.3
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

    @angular/cdk: 5.2.4
    @angular/material: 5.2.4
    @angular-devkit/architect: 0.5.5
    @angular-devkit/build-angular: 0.5.5
    @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.5.5
    @angular-devkit/core: 0.5.5
    @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.5.5
    @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
    @ngtools/webpack: 6.0.0-rc.3
    @schematics/angular: 0.5.5
    @schematics/update: 0.5.5
    typescript: 2.7.2
    webpack: 4.5.0
```

So I am greater then the 5.0 requirement for Angular Materials.
What am I missing?

My goal is to create an app to run in my VS2017 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resole this by utilizing yarn instead of npm.  It appeared to keep the dependencies together better then npm.  Therefore a lot less heartburn when trying to update Angular.

[Angular with Yarn](https://blog.angular-university.io/getting-started-with-angular-setup-a-development-environment-with-yarn-the-angular-cli-setup-an-ide/)